# python member variable of instance works like member variable, and some works like static variable

Tags: python

i'm python newbie, and member variable of class works weird in my python code.
some works like normal variable, but some works like static variable!

```
class Chaos:
    list_value = []
    value = "default"

    def set_value(self, word):
        self.list_value.append(word)
        self.value = word 

    def show(self, num):
        print(str(num) + "====")
        print("value : " + self.value)
        for st in self.list_value:
            sys.stdout.write(st)
        print("\n=====\n")

a = Chaos()
a.show(0)
a.set_value("A")
a.show(1)
b = Chaos()
a.show(2)
b.show(3)
```

result

```
0====
value : default

=====

1====
value : A
A
=====

2====
value : A
A
=====

3====
value : default
A
=====
```

but the last result of the test is different from what i expected in last test.
There should be no "A" in the 'list_value' of the instance of 'b'. 
It was just created, and never have been added 'A' before.
I added 'A'  to the instance of 'a', not 'b'. 
But the result show me that there are also 'A' in 'b'
More over, the 'list_value' and the 'value' in the class works differently. 
It looks like the both have same syntax. why do they work differently?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why class attribute is remembered?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713259/why-class-attribute-is-remembered)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Those are, in fact, class variables. To create instance variables, initialize them in the `__init__` function:

```
class Chaos:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list_value = []
        self.value = "default"
```

The reason `value` is behaving like instance variables is because you're setting it using `self.value`. When Python sees `self.X` it looks if there's a property `X` in your object, and if there is none, it looks at its class. Since you never set `self.list_value`, it's accessing the class variable, that is shared among all instances, so any modifiations will reflect in every other object.

Comment: The `list_value` will be the same in all instances because "list" is a mutable data type not because it's a class variable. If class variables are accessed through instances, they will behave like instance variables.

Comment: @aaronn That's a different issue than what was asked in the question. Mutable objects can cause problems when they are shared, through any means. But in this case nothing was shared, it's still the same class variable. The OP doubt arises from the fact that Python allows you to create new variables on the fly. That gives the impression that the `value` class variable is behaving like an instance variable, when in reality it's not. If the class had `__slots__` the difference would go away, neither variable would be allowed to change through the instance (only the mutable object pointed to).

Answer (score 3):

The key difference is that you are appending to `list_value`, and you are assigning to `value`.  They are called "class variables".  Each instance has its own reference to the class variable, which is why the list is shared.  However, when you assign, you are changing that instance's reference to point to a different variable, which explains the behavior of `value`.

If you are looking for instance variable behavior from `list_value`, initialize it in the constructor (a class method called `__init__`) instead.